# Cannot find name 'Office'

Tags: angular, typescript, office-js

I am using Angular 4 with Office.js. The project is created by Angular CLI.

The code is simple:

```
// declare const Office: any;
// With the line above, the app runs perfect

Office.initialize = function () {
  platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
};
```

I got the error

> Cannot find name 'Office'.

I already did `npm install --save-dev @types/office-js`

My tsconfig.json file:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2016",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

---

**UPDATE 1:**

Following @MahmoodSajjadi suggestion, after `npm install --save @microsoft/office-js`, and use

```
import { Office } from '@microsoft/office-js';
```

Got this error:

> ERROR in /my-app/src/main.ts (3,24): File
>   '/my-app/node_modules/@types/office-js/index.d.ts' is not a module.
>
> ERROR in ./src/main.ts Module not found: Error: Can't resolve
>   'office-js' in '/my-app/src'
>
> @ ./src/main.ts 3:0-35
>   @ multi webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:4200 ./src/main.ts

In package.json, actually it is `"@microsoft/office-js": "0.0.0"`, not sure this is a correct package.

---

**UPDATE 2:**

Based on Michael's answer, seems NPM version is not ready, I will stay with CDN version first. Thanks for everyone's help!

Comment: you need to declare Office or Import it (as your code comment)

Comment: @MahmoodSajjadi How can I import correctly? I tried `import { Office } from 'office-js';` but does not work.

Comment: the package `@type/office-js` is just type package and not an actual `office.js`, you need `npm i @microsoft/office-js`

Comment: @MahmoodSajjadi hmm, I did, now it is a different error, see my question UPDATE part.

Comment: It's not a module so you can import from it. Can still import it though, with `import 'office-js';` although the types should be picked up automatically without doing so

Comment: Also, you should specify your module format explicitly in tsconfig.json

Comment: @AluanHaddad my typo, still same error. In package.json, actually it is `"@microsoft/office-js": "0.0.0"`, not sure it is correct package.

Comment: I don't know what the relationship between those packages. The important thing is that you must only import from the module specifier matching the location of the JS

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It looks like you still need to specify that the `office-js` types should be used. Open up `src/tsconfig.app.json` and add `office-js` to the types array, which should then look like this if it was previously an empty array:

```
"types": [
  "office-js"
]
```

Next, you need to run the command `tsc -p tsconfig.json` from within your project directory before attempting to build the project again.

Comment: thank you for this, worked ! Don't forget to install the package: `npm install @type/office-js`

Answer (score 3):

The following works perfectly (note the package names)

```
npm install --save office-js @types/office-js
```

Then consume it as the global it declares.

```
Office.initialize(0);
```

Note that *office-js* is not a module, it is a global. Therefore we do not import from it. Rather the package becomes available ambiently.

If we wish to use import as a means to load *office-js* at runtime, we can add

```
import 'office-js';
```

In which case we are also not importing anything from it since there is nothing to import but we are stating a dependency on its execution, a side-effect of which is to create the global variable `window.Office`.

Note in your comments you mention an *@microsoft/office-js* package. At the time of this writing such a package exists but is completely empty, its entry point specifying a file that does not even exist, so I doubt that is the package you intend to use.

On an *unrelated* note, consider specifying your module format explicitly in your tsconfig.json file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs"
  }
}
```

It is a most important setting.

Comment: I did `npm install --save office-js @types/office-js`, but still same error `Cannot find name 'Office'.` And tried to add `"module": "commonjs"`, but still same.

Comment: Make sure your TypeScript is up to date (>=2.2.2). I tried it in an empty project. Works fine.

Comment: I needed this     "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ]
added to my tsconfig.js to make it work.

Answer (score 2):

For now, Office.js is consumed not as an NPM package, but as a CDN reference.  It's typings/d.ts *do* come from `@types`, but not its actual code.

I recommend you take a look at [Script Lab](https://github.com/OfficeDev/script-lab), a recently-announced tool and also open-source showcase sample, that uses Angular 4, and which you can use for inspiration.  Some of the underlying technology is also discussed in a [podcast about the project](https://blogs.office.com/2017/04/20/episode-127-new-script-lab-office-add-michael-zlatkovsky-bhargav-krishna-office-365-developer-podcast/).

Comment: So, I'm curious is the `npm:office-js` package deprecated?

Comment: It's more of the opposite: it's not yet fully-started.  We are thinking about moving to having NPM drops of our CDN, but there is some process involved to make this happen.  |  

And (at least for now), the Store requires CDN references for any Store-bound add-ins.  If you have feedback for why you'd rather host the files yourself via an NPM package rather than reference the official CDN, please consider adding your reasonings to https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641/suggestions/573756, so that it can be routed to the appropriate team.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. It makes the situation very clear. Actually, I'm concerned with the accuracy of my answer to this question. I don't want to be giving bad advice but it's the general advice that I would give for anyone trying to consume a package. That said, if I were to use this API I would like to install it directly.

Answer (score 0):

For me creating a variable naming 'Office' worked.

```
declare const Office: any;
(async () => {
    await Office.onReady();
    if (!Office.context.requirements.isSetSupported('ExcelApi', '1.7')) {
        console.log("Sorry, this add-in only works with newer versions of Excel.");
    }
})();
```