# Referencing office-js in a react-based Office Add-in

Tags: office-js

I'm working on an Excel Add-in and would like to reference office-js using an ES6 import like this:

import Office from '@microsoft/office-js'

Even though I've installed the package with npm and confirmed it's in my package.json I'm getting "Module not found" errors. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe it does not work that way. At least for the moment.

Have a look at this explanation.
[Cannot find name 'Office'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43599187/cannot-find-name-office?answertab=votes#tab-top)